# Fetch specific paramater from URL using react

Tags: reactjs

I have a URL like this that is created by external parties.

```
https://localhost:3001/succesful?code=3434443A&scope=xyz
```

I need to find the code and scope from the URL.

I tried to do it like this but not working

```
    const { code, scope} = useParams();
```

Could someone help me?

Comment: use [`useSearchParams`](https://reactrouter.com/en/main/hooks/use-search-params) or [`useLocation`](https://reactrouter.com/en/main/hooks/use-location#uselocation)

Answer (score 2):

Make sure you are using the **react-router-dom** library for the below solution.

```
import {    useSearchParams } from "react-router-dom";
```

You can refer to the below piece of code to fetch the information from the URL and use it in a particular component.

```
const [queryParameters] = useSearchParams()
```

and you can fetch code and scope like:

```
{queryParameters.get("code")}
{queryParameters.get("scope")}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
import {useSearchParams} from "react-router-dom"

function Home() {
  const [queryParameters] = useSearchParams()

  return (
    <div>
      <p>Type: {queryParameters.get("code")}</p>
      <p>Name: {queryParameters.get("scope")}</p>
    </div>
  )
}
```